# Setting default dynamic value for <select> option in Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I wanted to set default selected value for `select` option element but cannot get proper result

```
<template>
    <select v-model="tutor_work.start_year">
      <option>{{tutor_work.start_year}}</option>
      <option v-for="year in years" :key="year" :value="year">{{ year }}</option>
    </select>
<template/>
```

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            tutor_work: {
                organization: "",
                start_year: "",
                finish_year: "",
            },
        }        
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getUserData()
    },
    methods: {
        async getUserData() {
            await axios
                .get('api/v1/user/tutor/work/')
                .then(response =>{
                    this.tutor_work = response.data
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                })
        }
    },
    computed : {
        years () {
        const year = new Date().getFullYear()
        return Array.from({length: year - 1980}, (value, index) => 1981 + index)
        }
  }
}
</script>
```

The code works fine, but the problem is selected value (which is year) is on the first raw not after previous year, for example in the option there are years and `start_year: 2019` is from server and it's on the first option, not coming after 2018.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind `:selected="tutor_work.start_year"` :

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
    data() {
        return {
            tutor_work: {
                organization: "ff",
                start_year: "2010",
                finish_year: "2019",
            },
        }        
    },
    computed : {
      years () {
        const year = new Date().getFullYear()
        return Array.from({length: year - 1980}, (value, index) => 1981 + index)
      }
  }
}
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
    <select v-model="tutor_work.start_year">
      <option v-for="year in years" :key="year" :value="year" :selected="tutor_work.start_year">{{ year }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```